# Django save issue overwrites last entry

Tags: django

**Can anyone see any issues with the code below?** It's my save function for a model it gives them a GUID on first save. My my problem is when I save a new recipient (in the admin) it overwrites the last one added. Updates seem to work perfectly tho.

**part of Models.py**

```
class GUID():
    make = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.recipientid:
        self.recipientid = GUID.make
    super(Recipient, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is recipientid being used as your primary key? What does the whole model look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUID.make will be set at the time the GUID class is created, it won't re-calculated each time it's run. I don't know the rest of the context of how you're using GUID, but I'd have it be a function:

```
class GUID(object):
    @staticmethod
    def make():
         return hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()

...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.recipientid:
        self.recipientid = GUID.make()
    super(Recipient, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: the object bit isn't particularly important, it's just more modern way of defining classes.

Comment: Actually there doesn't seem to be any point in having this as a class at all. Just define a standalone function `make_GUID()`.

Comment: I agree, but I didn't want to suggest changing too much without understanding the greater context.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the way to do what you're trying to do is with a default lambda (in this example using a standard python uuid):

```
from django.db import models
from uuid import uuid4

class YourModel(models.Model):
    # ...
    recipientid = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=lambda: uuid4().hex)
```

Comment: that's useful to know thanks, but is there any reason for the behavior I'm seeing above with that code?